# How can I manually stack raw and jpeg files in Photos.app on Mac OS?

Tags: photos

I have a number of photos from a scuba diving trip last year that were shot with a camera that does RAW+JPEG (there wasn't an option for RAW only). At one point these were imported into iPhoto and then my library was later migrated into the newer Photos.app.

However, this results in a number of situations where my RAW and JPEG files aren't stacked as they're supposed to be. The metadata seems to line up (filename, timestamp, GPS coordinates), but they're still showing up as two different images.

[image: RAW+JPEG Photos Lined Up]

Is there a way to force Photos.app to stack the pairs of images together?